# Android Contents of response

Tags: android, saxparser

How to get the contents of response when the webservice returns a parsing error.
`Sax listner` has these methods

public void parsingSuccess(List list),

public void parsingError(String error)  &

public void connectionError(String error)

In case of error we just get the error message.Only when parsing is successful we get a list.
How to get the entire content  when there is a parsing error?

Comment: Set handler in error function and fill your list in it

Comment: how? could you please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

```
        Handler handler = new Handler(new Callback() {

                        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
                            this.list.setAdapter(); // set data to your list
                            return false;                           
                            }
                    });

public void connectionError(String error){
handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);// connection failder;
}
```

Comment: I already have a handler.This should be placed inside the parsing error method?

Comment: Callback callback=new Callback() { 
   
   @SuppressWarnings("unused")
   public boolean handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
    Logger.printLogI("weekly", "inside callback");
   
    return false;
   }
  };

Comment: You must set your List list field inside handleMessage

Comment: your Field list - global variable